Django Rest API - handling max_decimal_places more gracefully
Using Django Rest Framework and having a model that contains a decimal field like this:
rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

If a rate value is submitded with more than 2 decimal places I get a validation error with code "max_decimal_places".
I would like to handle things more gracefully and instead of raising an error I would like to round the rate to 2 decimal places. What's the best or even a good way of doing this. Overriding validation? Other options?
Thanks Stephan

You could probably override the to_internal_value method: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/9864c47018238dd9f8477df0e4ab2ef62a24fd2b/rest_framework/fields.py#L1023-L1049
